# AVAudioRecorder delegate method audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully: called too late

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I record a 5 second sound with `AVAudioRecorder.recordForDuration(5.0)`. Before I start a recording, I'm animating an image, and when recorder notifies us via delegate methods that it has stopped recording, I stop animating the image.
The trouble here is that delegate method `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` gets called almost half a second late, and I don't know why.
Because of this, users of the application have a feeling that we missed a part of what they wanted to record, and that's just awful.
For debugging purposes, I decided to track how much time every operation takes and it's obvious that it's audio recorder's fault.

So the question is: how can I speed up AVAudioRecorder? Or is writing on disk such an expensive operation?

Here are my time trackings:

```
audio recorder notified us about finishing: 5.51931619644165
we stopped animations: 5.51980209350586
recording duration: 5.01551020408163

audio recorder notified us about finishing: 5.56378316879272
we stopped animations: 5.5641040802002
recording duration: 5.01551020408163

audio recorder notified us about finishing: 5.53574800491333
we stopped animations: 5.53613710403442
recording duration: 5.01551020408163

audio recorder notified us about finishing: 5.50653314590454
we stopped animations: 5.50678110122681
recording duration: 5.01551020408163
```

Comment: Are you using objective-c or Swift?

Comment: @Jasper I use Swift.

Comment: Can you post your notification handler? Also, where are you recording to? Can there be a lag due to file management and that sort of thing? `AVAudioRecorder` is notorious for being a black box, if you want more control, you may need to go with a different framework.